# Determining if graph is a tree data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, directed-graph, undirected-graph

Problem I'm dealing with is pretty straightforward. Need to get simple `true` or `false` from a function.

My business domain with classes looks like this:

```
                                 A
                                / \
                               B   C
                                  / \
                                 D   E
```

Probably in future this will change, so it will not be a binary tree but it will still stay a tree, where each node can have multiple children.

Since I'm not very versed with all those fancy DS, I decide to relay on [tutorials](https://www.baeldung.com/jgrapht) and [libraries](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jgrapht/jgrapht-core/1.5.1). The code I came up is going like so:

```
import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.GraphTests;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.AsUndirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.GraphTests;

    @GetMapping("/b/{vertices}")
    public Object test2(@PathVariable("vertices") String vertices) throws IOException {
    
    
        List<String> possibleVertices = Arrays.stream(vertices.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
        DirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> directedGraph = new DefaultDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    
        possibleVertices.forEach(directedGraph::addVertex);
    
        if (possibleVertices.contains("A") && possibleVertices.contains("B")){
            directedGraph.addEdge("A", "B");
        }
    
        if (possibleVertices.contains("A") && possibleVertices.contains("C")){
            directedGraph.addEdge("A", "C");
        }
    
        if (possibleVertices.contains("C") && possibleVertices.contains("D")){
            directedGraph.addEdge("C", "D");
        }
        if (possibleVertices.contains("C") && possibleVertices.contains("E")){
            directedGraph.addEdge("C", "E");
        }
    
        AsUndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> unidirected = new AsUndirectedGraph<>(directedGraph);
    
        return GraphTests.isTree(unidirected );
    }
```

I tested all combinations and code is working as expected. However I do have couple of questions:

1. Is this library meant to use it in this way? That is, is mapping between vertices meant to be done in this manner?
2. Why do I need to convert from directed to undirected graph?
3. Since I'm working with Spring Boot, is it safe to use `@Bean` for creating `directedGraph`,  `unidirected` (possibly providing vertices to bean through lambda or something similar?) I do have doubts if those vertices with `addVertex` are not cached in some map within that object I'm invoking to construct the graph?
4. Is creation of any *grpah with `new` using this library expansive?

Comment: Why do you want Spring to come into this?

Comment: Because, I'm working in Spring Boot, and part of the service I'm implementing requires from me to get true/false info from this function. So mainly because of question 3. and 4. I'm interested to know if it would be more optimal to place creation of graph into @Bean.

Comment: I recommend you solve the Spring integration and the graph analysis parts separately.

Comment: any thoughts on why do you think spring is good/bad idea? and how would you handle graph analysis part

Comment: 1) I don't think Spring good idea vs bad idea comes into it.  Its more a case of not restricting yourself to only using Spring-blessed solutions.  And breaking your large problems down into smaller sub-problems that can be solved independently.  2)  Calls for recommendations.  All such questions are off-topic on StackOverflow.